# How to solve two javascript pop-ups conflict?

Tags: javascript, onclick, popup, mousemove

I built a simple pop-up that can open inline content and it is based on `add` and `remove` class. I want to use this pop-up two times on the same page, one as classic `onclick` pop-up and second should be triggered by `mousemove` (top of the page). 
To done this I changed pop-up IDs, but I cannot get through one conflict: When *mouse move pop-up* is opened it cant be closed.

```js
    // Pop-up
if (document.querySelector(".fl-pop-up")) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn_fl-pop-up");
    var modal = document.getElementById("fl-pop-up__init");

    // Open if exist
    if (btn) {
      btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.classList.add("fl-pop-up__active");
      };
    }
    
    var modal__overlay = document.querySelector(".fl-pop-up__overlay");
    var close = document.querySelector(".fl-pop-up__overlay--close");

    // Close on close click
    close.onclick = function() {
        modal__overlay.classList.remove("fl-pop-up__active");
    };
    // Close on window click
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal__overlay) {
        modal__overlay.classList.remove("fl-pop-up__active");
      }
    };
    // Close on ESC
    document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
      evt = evt || window.event;
      if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        modal__overlay.classList.remove("fl-pop-up__active");
      }
    };
  });
}

// Abandoning visitor
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var popupCounter = 0;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
  //    document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = "<br />X: " + e.clientX + "px<br />Y: " + e.clientY + "px";
  //});

  //jQuery(document).mouseleave(function () {
  var modal = document.getElementById("fl-pop-up__ab");
  //var modal = document.querySelector(".fl-ab-pop-up");

  if (mouseY < 50) {
    if (popupCounter < 1) {
      modal.classList.add("fl-pop-up__active");
    }
    popupCounter++;
  }
});
```

```css
.more-link {
position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
}

/* FL POP UP */
    .fl-pop-up {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000000;  
  }
    
    .fl-pop-up__overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.85);
    height: 100vh;
  }
.fl-pop-up__active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}  
  .fl-pop-up__overlay--pop-up {
    /*padding: 20px;*/
    background: #fff;
    width: 79%;
    height: 70vh;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
            box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  }
  
  .fl-pop-up__overlay--close {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1050;
    color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
    background-color: rgb(22, 22, 23);
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    background-position: 10px center;
  }
  .fl-pop-up__overlay--close:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
    <div id="btn_fl-pop-up" class="btn_fl-pop-up more-link">Open POP UP 1 - onclick</div>

<!--Onclick - POP UP 1-->
<div class="fl-pop-up">
<div id="fl-pop-up__init" class="fl-pop-up__overlay">
<div class="fl-pop-up__overlay--pop-up">
  <div class="fl-pop-up__overlay--close">×</div>
<div style="margin: 0 0 0 -15px;">
<div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align: center; the padding-top:3em;">
<h1 style="font-size: 2.2rem;">POP UP 1 (click)</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<!--Mousemove - POP UP 2-->
<div class="fl-pop-up">
<div id="fl-pop-up__ab" class="fl-pop-up__overlay">
<div class="fl-pop-up__overlay--pop-up">
  <div class="fl-pop-up__overlay--close">×</div>
<div style="margin: 0 0 0 -15px;">
<div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align: center; padding-top:3em;">
<h1 style="font-size: 2.2rem;">POP UP 2 (mousemove)</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question is meaningless. Always include your code along with your question and if it is executable code, include it within a "code snippet".

Comment: Fixed, thanks you.-)